# Generic container type with Strawberry GraphQL

Tags: python, strawberry-graphql

I want to create a generic Strawberry type for a pagination result:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

@strawberry.type
class CursorPaginationResult(Generic[T]):
    rows: List[T]
    next: str
```

This seems to work but i would like `CursorPaginationResult` to be a subclass of `StrawberryContainer` so that it can be unwrapped by strawberry-django. Is there a way to do this?

I intend to use this type like this:

```py
@strawberry.type
class ImtesQuery:
    items: CursorPaginationResult[Item] = CustomStrawberryDjangoField()
```

`CustomStrawberryDjangoField` would be a subclass of `StrawberryDjangoField` and take care the pagination logic and add arguments for `limit` and `cursor`.

Comment: I think this is something that will be supported when this PR lands: https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry/pull/1100